# Authentication in OpenVpn the way it's done in ProtonVpn for instance. Is it PAM?

Tags: vpn, openvpn, authentication

I'm trying to add authentication to my VPN server which is accessible via Internet and for browsing Internet.

At ProtonVpn, for instance, I'm given a login/password and upon connection OpenVpn daemon in the terminal asks me for them. I want to know how to achieve that? Is it done via "openvpn-auth-pam"? Or via some other way?

Answer (score 0):

The prompts are provided by the openvpn client in response to the `auth-user-pass` directive.

The client then passes the entered name and password to the server. The server will do as it has been configured to do. There are a number of options e.g. use pam, use a plugin and RADIUS etc.

What you use depends on your use case.

Comment: `What you use depends on your use case.` -> on mine or yours?